# libGDX text doesn't appear in TextField

Tags: java, android, libgdx

A game I'm working on has libgdx's TextField.  They work fine in every instance I've used them, however on a play tester's phone he says no typed text appears in the box until enter or space is pressed.  His specs:
Phone: S7 Edge Root: No Keyboard: Fleksy Android version: 6.0.1

The keyboard was causing some other issues (backspaces would not be recognized unless something had previously been typed into the box)  but when he switched to the stock keyboard his text still did not appear until pressing space or enter.

I have no problems on a couple of older phones running Android 5 and 4.  Has anyone experienced this or know a way to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Added code, though there really isn't much of my own.  I don't have access to the tester's device so I can't tell you exactly what is or isn't being executed.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField;
```

...

```
private TextField emailField;
```

...

```
String email = "email";
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
emailField = new TextField(email,skin);
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some code, this would help identify the problem (It could also be a bug in LibGDX).

Comment: Is the typo `TextFieldD` from the pasting progress or is that actually in your code?

Comment: That's not actually there.